# in ui-router, how to re-resolve only the most local state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following state tree, using ui-router,

```
1 login
2 root (abstract, resolves app-prefs, user-prefs)
    2.1 home (builds a refresh button, should refresh whatever is being shown)
        2.1.1 dashboard (resolves dashboard-prefs)
        2.1.2 search (resolves search-prefs)
        2.1.3 etc
    2.2 etc
```

From `home` when user presses refresh button while in `XYZ` state, I would like to have the `XYZ` re-entered in such a way that it re-resolves its own `XYZ-prefs` but not things above in hierarchy. Something like

```
$state.go("dashboard", dashboardParams, {please-resolve-only-dashboard})
```

When I try, from `home`

```
$state.go("dashboard", dashboardParams, {reload:true})
```

that causes *everything* from `root` downwards to get re-resolved, which is problematic, and expensive, as I need to re-resolve only `dashboard-prefs`. I can setup a more elaborate scheme in some resolvers to not re-resolve themselves but that might become a task by itself I'm afraid. Is there another, more idiomatic way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a wokring plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4gEOxQLhmH13rVitsDgG?p=preview)

There is a native way how to do that - just change the parameter of the state you want to reload.

To reproduce the above state definition let's have dashboard defined like this:

```
.state('dashboard', { 
  parnet: 'home',
  url: "^/dashboard",
  params: { updater : 1, },
  ...
})
```

What we can see, that we do not touch **`url`** at all. It will always be without any change just **`/dashboard`**

But we introduce really cool feature of the latest version - **`params: {}`**. It defines some parameter - `updater` in our case. Whenever this parameter is sent, and does differ form its current value, this child state *(and only this child state)* is **re-init**

Check it more about state `params: {}` here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

Now, we can create this reload link:

```
<a ui-sref="dashboard({updater : ($stateParams.updater + 1) })">reload</a>
```

And with this incrementation, we can be sure, reload will **reload** this state

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4gEOxQLhmH13rVitsDgG?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, this works (+1) but I also see that a new scope is spun [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zSBeM6PH4BcM15OqfF8u?p=preview). How does one harvest previous controllers; in particular if any listeners were attached in the controller then the listeners live on, and the scope also lives on.

Comment: I think that's a different question. I will close out this one.