# how to reload child state in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
<li ui-sref=".overview" 
    ui-sref-active="currentState"
    ui-sref-opts="{reload:true}">Flavors</li>
```

Config:

```
 .state('azure.overview', {
    url:'/azureOverview', 
    templateUrl  :'partials/azure/azureOverview.html', 
    controller : 'azureOverviewCtrl' 
  })        
controller $scope.init() { }
```

**I have used this snippet but my parent state also reloading but i want only child state to reload**

Comment: Can you show the config and the controller???

Comment: .state('azure.overview', {

  url:'/azureOverview',
  templateUrl :'partials/azure/azureOverview.html',
  controller : 'azureOverviewCtrl'

 })

controller
$scope.init()
{
get the data from server
}

Comment: whay are you passing .flavors as a statename

Comment: sorry i have updated code see now

Answer (score 2):

@Lakshmi You may have your answer here:

As of [0.2.14](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1809) you also have an option to just reload the current state and not it's parent.

So `$state.go(people.search, {}, {reload: true});` would reload the `people` state as well as all its childs.

While `$state.go(people.search, {}, {reload: "people.search"});` would not reload the `people` state but would reload `people.search` and its childs.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TFnQSqXl0DOkYdQyxbsi?p=preview)

Previously, for this question: [in ui-router, how to re-resolve only the most local state?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29640338/1679310), I created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4gEOxQLhmH13rVitsDgG?p=preview)

which shows, that we can use `params : {}` to define state parameter which is not in the url.. but could be used as **"change trigger"**, forcing just a child state to reload.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TFnQSqXl0DOkYdQyxbsi?p=preview) we can see these states:

```
  .state('azure', {
      url: "/azure",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.azure.html',
      controller: 'azureOverviewCtrl',
  })
  .state('azure.overview', {
      url: "/overview",
      params: { updater : 1, },
      templateUrl: 'tpl.overview.html',
      controller: 'OverCtrl',
  })
```

Now, we can create this **reload** link, which simply sends incremented *updater number*:

```
<li ui-sref-active="blue">
  <a ui-sref="azure.overview({updater: ($stateParams.updater + 1) })" 
  >Flavors <b>reloading</b></a></li>
```

And with this incrementation, we can be sure, that reload link - will **reload** this child state

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4gEOxQLhmH13rVitsDgG?p=preview)

Comment: it is reloading but ui-sref-active is not  working i have edited in plunker also but it is not working can you give sol for this Thanks in advance

Comment: @ Radim sure but i need sol plz

Comment: I udpated the answer, and created a plunker for you, with your stuff

Comment: plunker url please
I have seen above plunker but that is  not updated

Comment: i got ur plunker but the blue is not added when click on Flavors reloading

Comment: If we want to have in this constellation working also the ui-sref-active, we can do it like this plunker shows http://plnkr.co/edit/DTHu8eE4dtwXbvl4Ahs8?p=preview. Hope it helps, Enjoy mighty UI-Router

Comment: yeahhhhhhhhhhh its working fine but may i know why you have used two times same code
i mean 
<li ui-sref-active="blue" ui-sref="azure.overview({updater: ($stateParams.updater + 1) })">
      <a ui-sref-active="blue" ui-sref="azure.overview({updater: $stateParams.updater })" 
      >Flavors <b>reloading</b></a></li>

Comment: Yes you may now it ;) The trick is -  UI-Router needs direcitve **ui-sref** to be able to use *ui-sref-active*. The ui-sref, must be targeting the state - which is current. That means, that with one of these... we say to UI-Router ... we are really on current state. So - this is good for ui-sref-active. The second - which has different udpater value (different then current stat has) - is in fact there for us ... to really do redirect. So - both are needed, each for different purpose... taht's the angular world of directives ;) hope it helps. Good luck

Comment: oh got it , really really i am very thankful for your efforts... :) ;)

Comment: Well, if that helped, it would be nice if your accept this answer as helpful, maybe even upvote it ;) because that's how it is working here..

Answer (score 0):

The native, built-in functionality of ui-router is:

***when navigating among children, form one child state to another child, parent is NEVER reloaded***

unless we will explicitly change that built in behaviour, e.g. via decorator as you did and force the reload with passing these options:

```
  { reload: true}
```

You can also find similar type of solution in this post
[AngularJS UI Router $state reload child state only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316591/angularjs-ui-router-state-reload-child-state-only)

Comment: correct but i want reload same state how can I do that ?

Comment: <li
    ui-sref=".flavors({updater : ($stateParams.updater + 1) })"
    ui-sref-active="currentState">reload</li>

using this snippet i handled the reload fun. but ui-sref-active is not working]

Comment: add this to style :    ui-sref-active="currentState"
.currentState{
  background: blue;
}

Comment: i did same @Reena but its not working
ui-sref-active="currentState"
.currentState
{
 font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: @Lakshmi I think it might be because not in <a> tag. As I have seen many examples with this is working like http://plnkr.co/edit/KWxf2G9yGnOt05UbHFp9?p=preview